# Retrieving email and other information from facebook login in Android

Tags: android, email, android-studio, facebook-login

I want to retrieve users email and other information when he logs in from facebook. I was able to retrieve information when I tested on my device but when I ran the same app on other device it gives me null pointer exception. I have made the application change to public on facebook developers site. Stack trace is attached. I have added the email permission also. Not able to understand why I am able to retrieve in 1 device and not in other device.
Error log:

01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922): Process: com.example.logintest, PID: 9922
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at com.example.logintest.MainActivity$2$1.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:237)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:281)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1666)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
01-24 11:08:08.696: E/AndroidRuntime(9922):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Same problem for me. Any idea?

Comment: just check your hash key that you have set in facebook developer console and try to get the correct hash key for the development machine you are making the application. This would solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: My application is now available on google play. Users can login,there is no problem here generally. But sometimes their phones crash when they try to facebook login. I think   'Object objEmail=response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email"); ' sometimes return null. Because of that our app will crash sometimes.

Comment: There is a reason for that. Whenever you login to facebook there will be an option that whether you need to login with your email or phone number. So facebook supports login with phone number and when you try to fetch email address for that it will eventually crash. Just catch that exception in your code and try to take input from the user email at that point of time.

Comment: I realized that problem yesterday and I fixed that issue. I am waiting new "ANR and Crash Reports" from Console Developer page. I hope problem won't occur again.